# override table_prefix in custom module

Tags: database, resource-model

I develop a module with custom connection to custom database, and i'm using it through Mage_Core_Model_Abstract, Collection etc. 
But in exception.log i see

```
Exception message: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dbname.table_prefix_tablename' doesn't exist
```

But my custom db doesn't have a table prefix. 
I've tryed to override table_prefix

```
<global>
<resources>
<db><table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix></db>
<customdb_write>
...
```

but it doesn't work.
What can i do?

Answer (score 2):

try write install script

```
$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$this->getTable('test')} (
  `language_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `language` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description`varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`language_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `locale` (`country`,`language`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
");
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: but i'm working with a custom db. I don't need alter tables

Comment: you put create table syntax. it simple

Comment: See I update my code

Comment: i see, and so this installer writes in my custom db through config.xml connection?

Comment: yes that way. :)

Comment: I've tryed with echo $this->getTable('tablename') but the setup returned prefix_tablename

Comment: `$prefix = Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix();
echo $prefix;`

Comment: this will return your prefix name you have to use replace method.